# Start study Rails 4 or 3.2? What better for now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

Yesterday I started to study Rails, but, Ubuntu installed the version 4.0.0 stable.
I bought 3 books before that, and all these books are for 3.2 version.

My question is:

- Can I continue study version 4?
- Servers / Cloud / VPS are ready for it?
- The differences between 3.2 and 4.0 is huge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might as well keep going on Rails 4.  It will only be improved and 3.2 will stop being the version new Rails applications are being built with.  Rails 4 will probably be the version the applications are built in for a few more years.  Knowing Rails 4, you're pretty much able to understand older applications built in Rails 3, although dependencies are a problem if you start moving Rails 3 applications to Rails 4.  There's a very good Rails 4 tutorial at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book and you can use this site and your older Rails 3 books for quick reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just learning Rails, I wouldn't recommend creating Rails 4 apps with Rails 3.2 resources. If you're following along to your version 3.2 books, you should install Rails 3.2. You can manage multiple versions of Rails using [RVM](http://rvm.io).

My recommendation is start learning Rails 4. There are lots of Rails 4 resources available. As La-comadreja mentioned, Rails Tutorial is a good reference. Here are some others:

http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails-4

http://rubyonrails.org/documentation

http://www.codeschool.com/paths/ruby

Comment: Thanks my friend. I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

La-comadreja posted that railstutorial.org is based on rails 4.  However, I'm going through the tutorial and it actually uses rails 3.2.16. I'd post an image, or even comment but my reputation is not high enough.

Comment: This should be a comment under the answer, not as a separate answer. Just wait til you have enough rep to comment (very easy to do).

Comment: The e-book is available for both versions of Rails.  Look at the site.

Comment: You are correct, it's there, but from what I've seen its just an added chapter.  Its not very extensive.

Comment: The truth is that Rails 4 isn't *that* different from Rails 3, it's just different in some ways that are annoying to a Rails 3 programmer.